# Proof of 3-chain subsequence problem from assignment 2 of MIT OCW 6.042

Tags: induction, puzzle

I was trying to solve this question but stuck with how do I prove it so. I do have the intuition but how to prove it? Here is the link to the page and this one is the problem 1!!
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn02.pdf

***Don't tell all the answers but rather give a definitive hint or strategy for the first part!!***

Define a 3-chain to be a (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence
of three integers, which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. We
will show here that any sequence of five distinct integers will contain a 3-chain. Write
the sequence as a1, a2, a3, a4, a5. Note that a monotonically increasing sequences is one in
which each term is greater than or equal to the previous term. Similarly, a monotonically
decreasing sequence is one in which each term is less than or equal to the previous term.
Lastly, a subsequence is a sequence derived from the original sequence by deleting some
elements without changing the location of the remaining elements.

(a) [4 pts] Assume that a1 < a2. Show that if there is no 3-chain in our sequence, then a3
must be less than a1. (Hint: consider a4!)

(b) [2 pts] Using the previous part, show that if a1 < a2 and there is no 3-chain in our
sequence, then a3 < a4 < a2.

(c) [2 pts] Assuming that a1 < a2 and a3 < a4 < a2, show that any value of a5 must result
in a 3-chain.

(d) [4 pts] Using the previous parts, prove by contradiction that any sequence of five distinct
integers must contain a 3-chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part already contains a good hint. A little more explicit: Suppose the desired conclusion is false, i.e., $a1<a2$ and there is no $3$-chain, but $a3>a1$. How could you choose $a4$ without introducing a $3$-chain?

Comment: I think then I am confused about the 3-chain part only!! What I have understood about it from the question is that following are the possible combinations for the 3-chain -- a1-a2-a3, a1-a2-a4, a1-a3-a4, a2-a3-a4, a1-a2-a5, a1-a3-a5, a2-a3-a5, a1-a4-a5, a2-a4-a5, a3-a4-a5.  I think I am somewhere wrong with the concept only after reading your answer. Please help me figure out that!!

Comment: Those are the possible triples making up a $3$-chain, yes. For each of these there are two possible chains, i.e. for $a1-a2-a4$ you could have $a1<a2<a4$ or $a1>a2>a4$. In this question, you want to avoid all those possibilities, and in part 1, we are now assuming that we already have that $a1<a2$ and $a1<a3$. What can we deduce from this and from the absence of chains?

Comment: Got the first part!! So, do you mean to say that the line "there is no 3-chain in our sequence" means that there is no such chain out of all that i mentioned above ^^ let's say of the generic form x-y-z for which both x>y>z and x<y<z are possible( meaning only one of them can exit )?  And, I deduced from the assumption $a1<a2$ and $a1<a3$ is that then I don't know the relation between a2 and a3 thus the result becomes undefined!! But, if $a1>a3$ we can definitely say that $a3<a1<a2$ which surely doesnot follow the principles of 3-chain rule. Correct me over that wherever you feel so!!

Comment: One more thing, I am unable to get your question that you have asked in your answer -- "How could you choose a4 without introducing a 3-chain?". Please clarify on this better, or better you post your answer for the first part, although I thought I would solve it myself with the hints provided but I am stuck with it for around two hours, so you better explain it with a solution!! It might help me figure out what thing am I stuck at?

Comment: Yes, the condition means that none of those chains occur. So we cannot have $a1<a2<a3$, nor $a1>a2>a3$, nor $a1<a2<a4$, nor... Now it is true that $a1<a2$ and $a1<a3$ do not directly tell us how $a2$ and $a3$ are related. We could have $a2<a3$ or $a3<a2$. But note that one of these introduces a $3$-chain, so we must have the other (which?)

Comment: Once we have the relation between $a2$ and $a3$ figured out, the next question is where $a4$ fits in. Suppose for example that we have $a1<a3<a2$, there are in theory four options: $a4$ could be (1) less than $a1$, (2) between $a1$ and $a3$, (3) between $a3$ and $a2$, or (4) greater than $a2$. The question then is again which of these we can choose without introducing a chain; for example (4) is out since it would imply $a1<a2<a4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yeah, the comments :D

Answer (score 6):

**Non Contradictory proof -** 
A general proof goes like the way, that there are 5 nos,
 
a1 _ a2 _ a3 _ a4 _ a5. 
Now, since  **there are only 2 symbols available, '<' and '>'**, there will be **repetitions of symbols**. And since the question demands that the sequence should not be changed, so there will always be a 3 chain.
 For all possible combinations, **with minimum occurrence of each symbol = 2**, a 3 chain sequence can be formed by deleting. For eg.-

1. a1 < a2 > a3 < a4 > a5 | Chain - a1 < a2 < a4 or a2 > a4 > a5
2. a1 > a2 < a3 > a4 < a5 | Chain - a1 > a3 > a4 or a2 < a4 < a5


Answering the question in the form they asked - 
**Part 1** -
Now we assume a1 < a2.

So, the 5 numbers would be - a1 < a2 _ a3 _ a4 _ a5.
Proof by contradiction - 
**For propositon, lets assume, there is no 3-chain, but a3 > a1**. There arise 2 possibilities, which are - 

1 - a1 < a2 < a3
2 - a1 < a3 < a2

The first case cannot be taken(It forms the 3 chain)! In the second case, when we introduce a4, there are 4 possibilities,as - 

1 - a4 < a1 < a3 < a2
2 - a1 < a4 < a3 < a2
3 - a1 < a3 < a4 < a2
4 - a1 < a3 < a2 < a4

As we can see, all of them have a chain, (4,3,2),(4,3,2),(1,3,4),(1,2,4).
Thus, our assumption that a3 > a1, gave no possible combinations.

 Thus our assumption was wrong!!

**Part 2 -** 
Proof by contradiction - 
From part 1, we know that a3 < a1, the possible combinations that can be made from the three numbers are - 
1 - a3 < a1 < a2

**We are given the equation, a3 < a4 < a2, then the proposition will be, a4 < a3 or a4 > a2. This is just converse of the given statement.**
Adding a4 to the equation, we get combinations as- 
1 - a4 < a3 < a1 < a2
2 - a3 < a1 < a2 < a4
As we can see, both the combinations give a 3-chain combinations as (4,3,2),(1,2,4).
Thus the assumption that a4 < a3 or a4 > a2 is false, because it is given that there is no 3 - chain to be formed!
**Part 3 -** 
Proof by contradiction - 
From previous part, and the assumptions in this part, we know that the combinations can be - 

1 - a3 < a4 < a1 < a2
2 - a3 < a1 < a4 < a2

**The proposition for the proof can be that, adding a5 doesn't makes any 3 chain.**
Adding a5 to the equation, the possible positions can be - 
1 - a5 < a3 < a4 < a1 < a2
2 - a3 < a5 < a4 < a1 < a2
3 - a3 < a4 < a5 < a1 < a2
4 - a3 < a4 < a1 < a5 < a2
5 - a3 < a4 < a1 < a2 < a5

Every possible combination has a 3 - chain. (5,3,1),(5,4,2),(3,4,5),(3,4,5),(1,2,5).
Thus the assumption for a5 can be added to the equation, is wrong!!

In similar manner, the fourth part can be proved!!

Answer (score 3):

Klaus Draeger has helped you with the first part, and the other parts are similar. Just try to envisage the possible cases at each step of the game – there is no "strategy" involved in this solution approach.

Here is a proof involving less chasing of cases:

Let ${\bf s}=(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$ be given by
$$s_k:={\rm sgn}(a_{k+1}-a_k)\quad\in\{-1,1\}\ .$$
If ${\bf s}$ contains  two successive  entries of the same sign we are done. It remains to consider the case ${\bf s}=(1,-1,1,-1)$, since symmetry will then take care of $-{\bf s}$. When $a_4> a_2$ then $(a_1, a_2, a_4)$ is an ascending chain, and when $a_4< a_2$ then $(a_2,a_4, a_5)$ is a descending chain, since $s_4=-1$ says that $a_5<a_4$.

Comment: You can actually simplify this even more, since the problem specifies *distinct* integers, i.e. $s_k$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: @Klaus Draeger: Thank you. It seems that I was confused by the complicated explanation of monotonicity.

Comment: @KlausDraeger Why it would be so that $s_k$ cannot be zero? The question defines monotonic sequences with the inclusion of chances of having a term equal to the previous term for both monotonically increasing as well as decreasing sequence!!

Comment: @dex: The problem as stated involves "five distinct integers".

Comment: I am most probably having all the confusion with the 3-chain thing only. That's why I am to understand this as follows. I understand that when $a_4>a_2$ then $(a_1,a_2,a_4)$ is an ascending chain, but how come this happened that when $a_4<a_2$ then $(a_2,a_4,a_5)$ is a descending chain? This I could not understand, please try to explain this thing because I feel that it would help me to clear all my confusions regarding 3-chain thing.

Comment: okay, got that, missed that while reading their long definition. Have a look at this problem^^ too, please!!

Comment: okay, so you are taking $a_5<a_4$ because $a_4<a_2$ and if $(a_2,a_4,a_5)$ needs to be some chain, it would be so only if it satisfies this first condition of $a_5<a_4$. Isn't it so?

Comment: One last help, can you provide with the answer for the first part alongside the proof that you have given, because still a lot is going above my head including the thing that why you took the case of ${\bf s}=(1,-1,1,-1)$ ? It would be more than helpful, because I am also having confusion with what KlausDraeger was trying to convey through his answer, plus the fact that I am stuck with it for more than two hours!! Additionally, having one extra way of solving a single problem is something I always look forward to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got it!! :D