# Help understanding this proof of contradiction (integer sequence)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I'm [following a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1009336/389088) for this problem:

> Define a 3-chain to be a (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence of three integers, which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. We will show here that any sequence of five distinct integers will contain a 3-chain. Write the sequence as $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. Note that a monotonically increasing sequences is one in which each term is greater than or equal to the previous term. Similarly, a monotonically decreasing sequence is one in which each term is less than or equal to the previous term. Lastly, a subsequence is a sequence derived from the original sequence by deleting some elements without changing the location of the remaining elements.
>
> (a) [4 pts] Assume that $a_1 < a_2$. Show that if there is no 3-chain in our sequence, then $a_3$ must be less than $a_1$. (Hint: consider a4!)

The answer I linked to reads:

> Now we assume $a_1 < a_2$.
>
> So, the 5 numbers would be $ a_1 < a_2 ; a_3 ; a_4 ; a_5$.
>
> Proof by contradiction -
>
> For propositon, lets assume, there is no 3-chain, but $a_3 > a_1$. There arise possibilities, which are:
>
> $1 )\quad a_1 < a_2 < a_3$
>
> $2) \quad  a_1 < a_3 < a_2$
>
> The first case cannot be taken(It forms the 3 chain)

Ok that makes sense, the first case forms the chain $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$. The second case is not a chain? Maybe my English is not good enough, but why is this not a chain as defined in the problem?

The proof further goes on:

> In the second case, when we introduce $a_4$, there are 4 possibilities,as -
>
> $ 1)\quad  a_4 < a_1 < a_3 < a_2$
>
> $2)\quad a_1 < a_4 < a_3 < a_2 $
>
> $3)\quad a_1 < a_3 < a_4 < a_2 $
>
> $4)\quad  a_1 < a_3 < a_2 < a_4$

So, these are now chains, but $a_1 < a_3 < a_2$ is not? Can someone help me understand the reasoning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case, $a_1<a_3<a_2$ is not a chain because a chain is a **subsequence**, which means the order must remain the same. So $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a subsequence, but it is not a chain because it is not increasing and it is not decreasing (it goes up from $a_1$ to $a_2$, but then down from $a_2$ to $a_3$). For example, it could be that $a_1=1, a_2=5$ and $a_3=2$.

Then, $(1,5,2)$ is clearly not a chain, but $a_1<a_3<a_2$ (i.e., $1<2<5$) is clearly true

---

In the last part of the proof:

- If $a_4<a_1<a_3<a_2$, then $(a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is a decreasing chain.
- If $a_1<a_4<a_3<a_2$, then again, $(a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is a decreasing chain.
- If $a_1<a_3<a_4<a_2$, then $(a_1, a_3, a_4)$ is an increasing chain
- If $a_1<a_3<a_2<a_4$, then $(a_1, a_3, a_4)$ is an increasing chain

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense now, I didn't get the "order must remain the same" part.

Answer (score 0):

A $3-$ chain is an **ordered** triple. This means that the order, given by the indices, cannot be changed, and, if $a_1<a_3<a_2$ the triple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is not a chain.